# ASP.NET - Select and Display Gridview Row Data in Textbox using Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

Currently, I have a working code that selects and transfers gridview row data in a textbox. Here's the code

```
 protected void grdRP_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        GridViewRow row = grdLocation.SelectedRow;
        hdnSearchedLoc.Value = grdLocation.Rows[grdLocation.SelectedIndex].Cells[1].Text;
        txtSearchedLoc.Text = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(row.Cells[2].Text);


    }
```

It works well functionality and performance (speed) wise when it is local. I have seen the difference in speed when I upload it to the web server. it takes 5 seconds and more before it transfer the row  data to textbox.

Now, I am thinking of alternative way to make it faster by using javascript since it is on client-side. I have seen a sample code but it is only on selection method but the transfer of row data is still the same speed. Here's the code

javascript

```
function setMouseOverColor(element)
{
    oldgridSelectedColor = element.style.backgroundColor;
    element.style.backgroundColor='#C0C0C0';
    element.style.cursor='hand';
    //element.style.textDecoration='underline';
}

function setMouseOutColor(element)
{
    element.style.backgroundColor=oldgridSelectedColor;
    element.style.textDecoration='none';
}
```

aspx.cs

```
 protected void grdRP_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Row.Cells[0].Style["display"] = "none";

        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {

            e.Row.Attributes["onmouseover"] =
                "javascript:setMouseOverColor(this);";
            e.Row.Attributes["onmouseout"] =
                "javascript:setMouseOutColor(this);";

            e.Row.Attributes["onclick"] =
            Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink
                (this.grdRP, "Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex);


        }
    }
```

**is there other javascript way of doing that?**

Comment: I'm confused you went from changing values to changing colors to make things faster?

Comment: changing colors of gridview row on mouseover and mouseout event is just part of the features,  I did not mean that those two mouse events are my answers. However the onclick event there I think is the one, but it is still slow, or did not contribute at least improvement in speed